# No appropriate default constructor available and no default constructor exist

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++ and trying to write a "Date Class" program that make some calculations on dates.

These two errors appear to me:

> error C2512: 'Date' : no appropriate default constructor
>
> IntelliSense: no default constructor exists for class "Date"

In the line that i have declare an object from the class:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Date d;
}
```

The constructor in the `.h` file:

```
public:
      Date(int, int, int);
```

The implementation:

```
Date::Date(int d= 0, int m= 0, int y= 0)// DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR 
{
      d = m = y = 0;
}
```

Please help me, why this error appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

The constructor in the .h file:

```
public: 
      Date(int=0, int=0, int=0);
```

The implementation:

```
Date::Date(int d, int m, int y)// DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR  
{ 
      // Initialize data of this class
}
```

The prototype/declaration of method should mention the default arguments, not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add such constructor as well:

```
public:
     Date();
     Date(int, int, int);

Date::Date()// DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR 
{
     d = m = y = 0;
}
```

Comment: 1- I do this changes .. the 2nd error just is gone .. th 1st still there .

2- How i initialize [ d, m, y ] without send them as a parameter

Comment: What happens when you have this code: `Date d(10, 10, 2011);`?

Comment: I want  a constructor that takes `Date today(2011, 8, 25);`.