# Getting C2512 "no default constructor" for `ClassA` error on the first parentheses of constructor for `ClassB`?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My situation is as follows. Let there be a header file `classdeclarations.h`, where I have the following classes declared:

```
class ClassA;
class ClassB;

class ClassA
    {
    public:
        ClassA(int x);
        ClassA(double y);

        int ReturnInteger(void) { return m_x; }
        double ReturnDouble(void) { return m_y; }
    private:
        int m_x;
        double m_y;
    }

class ClassB
    {
    public:
        ClassB(int x);

        int ReturnInteger(void) { return m_x; }
    private:
        int m_x;
        ClassA m_InstanceA_1;
    }
```

Let there be a `*.cpp` file called `classdefns.cpp`, where I define methods of the classes declared in `classdeclarations.h`:

```
#include classdeclarations.h

ClassA::ClassA(int x) : m_x(x)
    {
    }

ClassA::ClassA(double y) : m_y(y)
    {
    }

ClassB::ClassB(int x) : m_x(x)
    {  //  this is the line where the build error occurs
    m_InstanceA_1 = ClassA(0);
    }
```

Note that I have commented the line where the compiler says there is an error:

`error C2512: 'ClassA' : no appropriate default constructor available`

The above example is not a minimal not working example (it probably works), but it captures the gist of the more complicated situation where I am getting the error.

[This StackOverflow question regarding the same error was resolved by an answer that clarified where default arguments should be specified.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191159/no-appropriate-default-constructor-available-and-no-default-constructor-exist) I do not have default arguments in my situation anymore (but did, in the past). I just double checked to make sure there are no default constructor arguments.

[This question regarding the same error was resolved by ensuring that the name of the constructors was the same as the name of the class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989357/c2512-error-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available) I have double checked to make sure that is not the issue with my situation.

[This question regarding the same error is different from my case, because here the asker did not want to have a default constructor defined.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028691/c-error-c2512-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available)

[This question regarding the same error was resolved by ensuring that a default constructor method was declared in the body of the class declaration.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434234/no-appropriate-default-constructor-available-error) So, it is not applicable to my case since I already have the constructors declared in the class declaration as well.

[This question regarding the same error was resolved by ensuring that the declaring header file was properly included.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660314/c-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available) This is not the problem in my situation.

**[This question regarding the same error is perhaps relevant, but I don't understand it well enough, and would appreciate clarification on where I might be assuming the existence of a default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850765/error-c2512-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available-not-classes)**

Comment: Make it `ClassB::ClassB(int x) : m_x(x), m_InstanceA_1(0) {}`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I made an edit to the question because I realized I made a typo. Does your comment still hold?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: AS answers have been given, you should read up on the difference between initialization and assignment in constructors. m_InstanceA_1 is always constructed before it is initialised.

Comment: @djgandy Thank you. This has been a good lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClassB::ClassB(int x) : m_x(x), m_InstanceA_1(0)
                                //^^^^^^^^^^^^, this constructs the ClassA instance
{
}
```

### Edit

> Getting C2512 “no default constructor”

If you still need the ability to default construct a `ClassA` instance then you need to add a default constructor. The default constructor is no longer auto generated once other constructors are provided.

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(); // Provides a default constructor declaration (you still need to implement it)
    ClassA(int x);
    ClassA(double y);

...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I made an edit to my question because I realized I made a typo. Does your answer still hold?

Comment: `m_InstanceA_1` (of type `ClassA`) is still a member of `ClassB` so this initialization still applies.

Comment: Hmm. I think I need to initialize `m_InstanceA_1` within the body of the `ClassB` constructor, because while for this example I have just provided a simple `0` to be fed to `ClassA`'s constructor, in my situation, I need to do some calculations in the body of `ClassB` before I can know what values I should use to construct `ClassA`. Does this mean that I should first create a default instance of `ClassA` for `m_InstanceA_1` and then do the necessary calculations in the body of `ClassB`'s constructor, and then set the member variables of `m_InstanceA_1` correctly?

Comment: You can still do it in the initialization list `ClassB::ClassB(int x) : m_x(x), m_InstanceA_1(/* perform the computation here*/)` or `ClassB::ClassB(int x) : m_x(x), m_InstanceA_1(/* call a function to perform a complex computation */)`.

Comment: @user89: If possible, try to extract "some calculations" to a private static method which you can then use to initialize `m_InstanceA_1`.  For example: `ClassB::ClassB(int x) : m_x(x), m_InstanceA_1(CalculateX()) {}`.

Comment: Thanks all very much! This fixes the issue.